# Highcharts: How to add more than 1 intermediateSum in Waterfall chart?

Tags: charts, highcharts, waterfall

Consider, JS fiddle where waterfall chart has 2 intermediate sums defined http://jsfiddle.net/xsoadwzk/

```
{
  name: 'Service Revenue1',
  isIntermediateSum: true,
  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
}, {
  name: 'Service Revenue2',
  y: 231000
}, {
  name: 'Positive Balance',
  isIntermediateSum: true,
  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
},
```

Here, it was expected that, Service Revenue1 and Positive Balance are plotted as intermediate sums showing summary.

Is there a way to achieve multiple intermediate sum in waterfall chart using Highcharts library?

Comment: I can't really tell what you are trying to achieve, could you make a mockup in paint or similar to show what you want to happen. I assume this is not what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/xsoadwzk/1/ ?

Comment: @ewolden The fiddle you shared is exactly what i wanted to achieve. But i didnt understand why Positive Balance is set as isSum? I interpreted that any summary columns between start and end have to be defined as intermediate sums.